# How to reduce the time counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, javascript-objects, dom-events

Need to reduce the timing  for the set times.
E.g. user logout time is  14:23:30 means  need to show the remaining time seconds to the user.
Need to show the counter reducer time in Javascript.

Here is a timer. Like that how to reduce the time  from after two minutes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a countdown timer? -- https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are trying to get:

```js
var initTime = new Date();
var i = 0;

function myTimer(){

  i++;
  var newTime = new Date(initTime.getTime() - i * 1000);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =     newTime.toLocaleTimeString();
  
}

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: hi how could do the timer from two min look through this and set the time counter from two minutes  [link]https://jsfiddle.net/Mohamed_Sahir/s162qa8b/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement timer and want to calculate based on logout time.

```
var sampleTimer = (function() {
 var today = new Date(),
 logoutTime = "14:23:30".split(":"),
 logoutTimeInsec = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), logoutTime[0], logoutTime[1], logoutTime[2]).getTime();

return  function() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('check');
  if (logoutTimeInsec - currentTime > 0) {
   setTimeout(sampleTimer, 1000);
  }
}

}());
```